# How do I add text to a gauge's ticks?

Tags: highcharts

I have multiple gauges designed similarly to this one I found in another answer: http://jsfiddle.net/Fe6yJ/790/

In my gauges, I don't have regular ticks but I do have a consistent number of ticks in each gauge, each representing a certain limit in my system. I want to add text to the ticks to indicate what they mean. Pseudocode of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
// gauge1
tickPositions: [100, 200, 300, 400]
tickNames: ["normal", "heavy", "warning", "critical"]

// gauge2
tickPositions: [150, 250, 500, 525]
tickNames: ["normal", "heavy", "warning", "critical"]
```

Basically, the tick names will be the same across gauges but the positions may be different. In the end result, what I want to see on the gauges are ticks which would say something like

```
normal (150)
heavy (250)
warning (500)
critical (525)
```

Or some similar text format as long as it's a name-value pair. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use label.formatter function. Inside this function it will be possible to set your label to a specific string, depending on its value. Here you can find code that may help you:

```
labels: {
    enabled: true,
    distance: 20,
    formatter: function() {
      var value = this.value, string;
      if (value < 33) {
        string = 'normal'
      } else if (value < 66) {
        string = 'heavy'
      } else if (value < 100) {
        string = 'warning'
      } else string = 'critical';
      return string;
    }
  },
```

And here you can see live example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/Fe6yJ/935/